# Why do expressions with physical units not get simplified?

Tags: physics, units, physical-constants

I am trying to calculate precise values for certain expressions, see the image below.
[image]

The output `testZPF` of the function $\Delta$Fn should be a single output. I am trying to understand why Mathematica does not provide me with a single number in fully simplified units (here the dimension of the result is $[m]$), but instead prints the result in units of $c$ and $\hbar$.

**Edit**

For the dimensions, I tried to use `UnitConvert`, but get an error here. The error is very strange as the result should have indeed dimensions $[m^{-1}]$.
[image]

**Edit 2**

Here is the code:

```
\[Omega] = 
 2 Pi*Quantity[1, 
   "SpeedOfLight"]*(1/Quantity[735, "Nanometers"] - 
    1/Quantity[900, "Nanometers"])
Subscript[m, red] = Quantity[6, "AtomicMassUnit"]
Subscript[h, bar] = Quantity[1, "ReducedPlanckConstant"]

\[Del]Fn[\[Omega]_, m_] := Sqrt[Subscript[h, bar]/(\[Omega]*m)]
testZPF = \[Del]Fn[\[Omega], Subscript[m, red]]
UnitConvert[testZPF, "Meters"^(-1)]
```

Comment: You have all integers and symbolic numbers (`\[Pi]`) in your equations. Mma uses infinite precision in these cases.  You can move to machine precision by following your integers with a decimal; e.g. `1.` instead of `1`. This makes them machine precision reals and you'll get reals in the output.

Comment: Ok, but what about the dimensions? How can I simplify them? I tried to use UnitConvert, but got an error. See edit to question above.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. Please, provide your code as a copy-paste text, not as a screenshot. Furthermore, check [`UnitSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitSimplify.html).

Comment: @Domen Thanks, I added the code and still have the same problem.

Comment: First of all, do not use character ∇ as part of the symbol name as it [gets interpreted](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Del.html) as ``Del[...]``. Secondly, as I have proposed, use ``UnitSimplify`` and you will get [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVBoS.png) in picometres. Thirdly, you can use ``UnitConvert[testZPF, "Meters"]``.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ω = 
  2 Pi*Quantity[1, 
    "SpeedOfLight"]*(1/Quantity[735, "Nanometers"] - 
     1/Quantity[900, "Nanometers"]);
Subscript[m, red] = Quantity[6, "AtomicMassUnit"];
Subscript[h, bar] = Quantity[1, "ReducedPlanckConstant"];

∇Fn[ω_, m_] := Sqrt[Subscript[h, bar]/(ω*m)]
testZPF = ∇Fn[ω, Subscript[m, red]]
```

[image]

Using the default conversion ("SIBase")

```
UnitConvert[testZPF]
```

[image]

Using other unit systems may not convert all constants

```
{#, UnitConvert[testZPF, #]} & /@ {"Conventional", "Imperial", 
  "Metric", "SI", "SIBase"} // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

You can convert to any compatible unit, i.e., a distance

```
UnitConvert[testZPF, # <> "meters"] & /@ 
  {"centi", "milli", "micro", "nano", "pico"}
```

[image]

As pointed out by Domen

```
UnitSimplify[testZPF]
```

[image]